# Send video/audio over socket.io from browser

Tags: node.js, socket.io, getusermedia

I am trying to send video and audio trought socket.io but I geting Buffer on the end how should I handle it?

Here is my code:

SERVER,  HERE I RECIVE BUFFER:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('radio', function (image) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('radio-reciver', {count: 1, buff: image});
    })
})

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started!')
});
```

CLIENT:

//PART FOR SENDING VIDEO/AUDIO

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, loadCam, loadFail)

function loadCam(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            var media = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            media.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                socket.emit('radio', e.data);
            }


            media.start(1000)
            logger("Cam is ok")
}
```

//PART FOR RECIVING, HERE I RECIVE BUFFER

```
socket.on('radio-reciver', function (image) {

            var sourceStream = MediaSourceStream({  // Creates a writable stream
                mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"'
            })
            image.pipe(sourceStream)

            var img = document.getElementById('play');
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(sourceStream.mediaSource);
            $('#logger').text(image);
        })
```

As you see I am using media recorder to transfer data but not working... Any example how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing `image.pipe()`, you should probably use:

```
sourceStream.write(image);
```

You're going to be receiving chunks here, as Buffer objects.  Not a stream.

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at validChunk (media-source-stream.js:1779)

Comment: This is example of repsonse image.buff ArrayBuffer(271997) {}

Comment: `sourceStream.write(image.buff)` then?

Comment: Yes I used that

Comment: Is there a way to get it as streaming?